# Excel is reference by the Sharepoint Site name instead of Site URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, url, formula

Recently migrated files into SharePoint Online via ShareGate tool.

There is an excel, which has many formula referencing to different excels. All hosted in same site (but different libraries) in SharePoint online.

The formula is only working if we reference by site name instead of Site collection URL.

**Working:**  `='https://XXXXXXXX.sharepoint.com/SiteName/Shared Documents/[test.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$6`

**Not Working:** `='https://XXXXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/System-portal/Shared Documents/[test.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$6`

where as in other SharePoint site it is working with only complete direct URL but not with Site name.

When I am trying to get the access the site via site name it showing 404 error in browser.

does any body have any Idea, how Excel is reaching to this site even with the wrong reference ?

Comment: Whether this issue occurs to all excel files in this site collection?

Comment: actually only one file has it. and I haven't tried creating any new file in the same Site Collection.

Comment: Try to delete the issued file, re-upload it into SharePoint Online, then test the URL.

Comment: The issue is, the original file has been deleted permanently.